# Semicolon inside function parentheses?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I was browsing through Psycle source code, and this line caught my attention:

```
bool user_choose_dialog(HWnd const window_handle,
                        format const * const source_format = 0,
                        format const * const proposed_format = 0;
                        std::string const & caption = "");
```

As you can see, there's a semicolon in the parameter list. I noticed there was an old question about this, and the answer was that the semicolon was used for forward declaration. However, I can't see a forward declaration in this situation. What's the meaning of that semicolon there? Is it something meaningful and functional, or is it a typo in the source?

Comment: Does the code compile?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have compiling tools on this computer. I was just curious. That source line was in a header file, and the corresponding function definition in the source file didn't have the semicolon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
format const * const proposed_format = 0;
```

It's simply misprint, I think. It should never compile.

Comment: +1 I concur (and thank you fox fixing the double-negative =P)